# android notifications with a future date

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

i am looking for an solution, to generate an notification, which will shown for example 5 seconds after notification was generated.

for this, i found this example:
https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223

i do it exactly like this, but no notification will be active in my app.
another "problem is" that android studio tells me, that builder.build() requires api 16 - but i have to use min api 15

can somebody helps me?

**NotificationPublisher**

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("5 second delay"), 5000);

    }


    private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long futureInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon);
        return builder.getNotification();
    }

}
```

Comment: Before API 16, you use the `getNotification()` method instead of `build()`. Other than that, we'd have to see your code to help you.

Comment: please look at the link of my first post - i use the same code. i added my code to post 1

Comment: Is it working with `builder.getNotification()`? Your initial question should be answered by Mike M.

Comment: i change builder.build() to builder.getNotification()- Android Studio show no more error. but the notification will not be shown

Comment: Did you register the Receiver in the manifest? Is the Receiver in the same folder as the Main Activity?

Comment: yes, i put <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher" /> into my manifest before the application tag close. and yes, the receiver is in the same folder as the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not the same as the example. The following line:

```
long futureInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
```

should be:

```
long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
```

Comment: thats right ! I change it and now it works. but what is the difference and why doesn't work it with System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: It would work that way if you set the alarm type as `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`. Elapsed time is the time since the last boot up. Real time is, well, real time; i.e., "wall clock time".

Comment: okay, and what would you prefer? System.current oder SystemClock?

Comment: Depends on your situation. If you just need alarms set in the near future for the current session in your app, elapsed time is fine. If you're scheduling alarms for specific dates and times in the future, real time is easier to deal with.

Comment: okay thank you very much for that :) 
BUT one question more. i would like to set 2 Notifications. at the moment, overtime the notification id 1 will set. i think i have to set this every time plus 1. is there an simple way to do this. at the moment i would save the id into user prefs and count this + 1

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the easiest way to do that.